# php scope resolution operator with the keywords static and self

Tags: php, oop

I am looking over the difference between the `self` and `static` keywords used in OOP PHP and am having a hard time noting the differences or when to use which one.

Example:

```
class T {
    public static $a = "a";

    public static function p() {
        echo static::$a;
    }

    public static function pp() {
        echo self::$a;
    }
}

T::p();
T::pp();
```

both methods do the same thing. What is the purpose of `static` in this type of OOP context and should you use either `self` or `static`?

Comment: Try `self` outside of the `class`.

Comment: it's called [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)